# Can Forefront TMG server as an outbound chacheing solution to a web farm

Tags: web-server, datacenter, microsoft-forefront-2010

We are to deploy several web servers in a datacenters. All running Windows 2K12 + IIS.
I am not very familiar with data center best practices for deploying and maintaining web servers.

In the office we've used Forefront TMG to secure the perimeter and publish internal web-sites.

Will Forefront TMG act as a caching proxy to facilitate content delivery to a clients requesting resources from TMGs intranet?

What we've seen is a pretty good performance when it comes to inbound content caching on TMG.

I am concerned that TMG will only slow things down and my web servers don't need perimeter protection at all (just good patching and well-configured firewall).

Comment: Can TMG do Reverse Proxy Caching - Yes. The settings are essentially the same for forward proxying.